# screen recordar for old ipad and ios 10.3.3

Tags: ipad, screen-recording

I have an Ipad from 2013, with what I think is the most updated version possible for it which is IOS 10.3.3. I need to record the screen to have videos of my writting in notability, but unfortunately this version does not have screen recorder incorporated.

Does anybody knows how to do it? I checked before, and apparently using AirShou was a good solution, but I could not download it for some reason.

Comment: How about AppValley or Cool Pixel Screen Recorder? Both tools are good for your IOS version. Have you tried it?

Comment: Do you have a Mac handy? You can connect use QuickTime Player.app running on your Mac to record the iPad's screen.